# A problem on $3\times3$ magic square. Prove that the element at the centre of the grid is $9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A $3 × 3$ magic square is an arrangement of the numbers from a set of
> odd integers ${1, 3, 5, . . . , 17}$ in a $3×3$ square grid, where the numbers
> in each row, in each column, and in the main and secondary diagonals,
> all add up to $27$. Prove that the element at the center of the grid is $9$.

The solution given is:

Let us assume that the element at the center of the grid is not $9$. Without loss of generality, let us assume that it is less than $9$, i.e., it is some odd integer $k$, where $k < 9$.

Now, let us consider the row, column, and diagonal that contain $k$. Since the sum of each row, column, and diagonal must be $27$, and since the element at the center of the grid is not $9$, it follows that the sum of the elements in the row, column, and diagonal that contain $k$ must be greater than $27$.

However, since $k < 9$, each of the other six numbers in the grid must be greater than $9$, since they must add up to $18$ (the sum of the odd integers from $1$ to $17$, excluding $k$). This means that each of these six numbers must be at least $11$.

Thus, the sum of the row, column, and diagonal that contain $k$ is at least:

$k + 11 + 11 + 11 = k + 33$

Since $k$ is an odd integer less than $9$, it follows that $k + 33$ is an odd integer greater than $41$. But this is impossible, since the sum of the odd integers from $1$ to $17$ is $81$, which is less than $41$ times $3$.

Therefore, our initial assumption that the element at the center of the grid is not $9$ must be false. Hence, the element at the center of the grid must be $9$.

Can it be solved in another way? Also I don't know this solution is correct or not....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose the board is filled by:

> $$a,~ b,~ c\\
> x,~y,~z\\
> p,~ q, ~r$$

We can list the equations according to the requirement.

Top row and bottom row:

$$\begin{align}a+b+c=27\tag{1}\\
\\
p+q+r=27\tag{2}\end{align}$$

Middle column:

$$\begin{align}b+y+q=27\tag{3}
\end{align}$$

Two diagnols:

$$\begin{align}a+y+r=27\tag{4}\\
\\
c+y+p=27\tag{5}
\end{align}$$
Simplify:
$$\begin{align}(1)+(2)-(3)&\Rightarrow a+c+p+r-y=27\tag{6}\\
\\
(4)+(5)&\Rightarrow a+c+p+r+2y=54\tag{7}\end{align}$$

Finally,

$$(7)-(6)\Rightarrow 3y=27\Rightarrow y=9$$

Answer (score 2):

I think you are complicating it. Assign $x_1, x_2, ... ,x_9$ to the cells from right to left. You have $$x_1+x_5+x_9=27$$$$x_2+x_5+x_8=27$$$$x_7+x_5+x_3=27$$$$x_4+x_5+x_6=27$$ Sum them up you have $(x_1+x_2+...+x_9) + 3x_5=118$. That would give $x_5=9$ since the sum of those odd numbers is 81.

Comment: You meant $108$ rather than $118$.